# connecting to packet tracer from pc

Tags: cisco, router, putty, gns3

How I can connect to a router that runs in Packet Tracer from the pc that the program (Packet Tracer) runs on it using telnet or Putty or SecureCRT or other shell programs?
I use GNS3 but need to work with Cisco 2800 routers so need to use Packet Tracer.

Answer (score 3):

PacketTracer is just an educational software and not an emulator such as GNS3, which is actually an interface for dynagen, visit [dynagen](http://www.ipflow.utc.fr/index.php/Cisco_7200_Simulator) for more infomation. PacketTracer can't actually create packets or do anything real, they just 'feel' real for educational proposes.
Visit [cisco](http://www.cisco.com/web/learning/netacad/course_catalog/PacketTracer.html) and they will tell you.